# Proof for prime factorization

Tags: proof-verification, prime-factorization

Suppose that S is a finite set of odd primes, each of the form 4k+3 for some natural k.
Let z be the product of the numbers in S, plus 3.
Would this be a false statement about the prime factors of z?

*We can't tell whether they include another 4n+3 prime -- it depends on S.*

I have been trying to understand Gaussian but the "plus 3" in the z is confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is true.  If, for example, we take $S=\{3\}$ then $z=6$ and $z$ has no prime factor of the form $4k+3$ other than $3$, which is in $S$. On the other hand, taking $S=\{11\}$ we get $z=14$ which is divisible by $7$.

It is true that $z$ must be divisible by a prime not in S.

To see this note that $$z=\prod_{p_i\in S}\; p_i+3$$ is relatively prime to every $p_i$ except $3$ (if $3$ happens to be one of the $p_i$).  Thus the only way $z$ might only have prime factors from S is if $3\in S$ and $z$ is a power of $3$.  But, $3^n-3$ is even, hence could not be the product of the primes in S.

Comment: I'm sorry, so is this a false statement?

Comment: I believe it is, yes.  $z$ must be divisible by a prime not in $S$ (I will edit my posted solution to clarify).

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  The statement is true.  I am amending my posted solution.